# Como traduzir o aplicativo Android?

Tags: android

Criei a pasta values-es, com o arquivo strings.xml com items no string array.

Porem quando coloco no celular a tradução pra espanhol, abro o aplicativo e nada ocorre, continua português.

Comment: Suponha que traduzia também para inglês. O acha que irá acontecer no celular? Como é que ele irá escolher entre 3 línguas?

Comment: ingles seria a padrao, e eu criaria uma values-pt, não? mas o problema que nao funciona, por enquanto ta padrao portugues, a pasta values rais, ta com portugues.

Comment: Você não respondeu às minhas perguntas. Pondo de outra forma: Como é que o celular sabe qual o idioma a utilizar quando uma aplicação tem definido mais do que um idioma?

Comment: Não sei, como é?

Comment: Tem que alterar o idioma do celular de português para espanhol.

Comment: Sim isso que fiz, como mencionei no post, mas nada ocorre.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19056/discussion-between-war-lock-and-ramaral).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Para fazer que seu aplicativo funcione com múltiplos idiomas, você deve criar no seu projeto pastas *values* de acordo com o idioma e região de interesse, os idiomas são identificados por dois caracteres, conforme a [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) e as regiões também são identificadas por depois caracteres, precedida pela letra "r", conforme a [ISO 3166-1-alpha-2](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search), as regiões não são obrigatórias.

Por exemplo:

```
/
/res/
/res/values-pt
/res/values-pt-rBR
/res/values-en
/res/values-en-rUS
```

Dentro de cada pasta *values* dessas, deve existir um arquivo chamado *strings.xml*, que contém uma chave única (dentro do mesmo arquivo) e o valor correspondente ao idioma da pasta.

Vou deixar um exemplo mais completo que pode te ajudar:

Valores padrões (`/res/values/strings.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nome_aplicacao" translatable="false">Multi-idioma</string>
    <string name="opcao1">Padrão</string>
    <string name="opcao2">Inglês</string>
    <string name="opcao3">Espanhol</string>
    <string name="mensagem">Um teste</string>
</resources>
```

Valores em Inglês (`/res/values-en/strings.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="opcao1">Default</string>
    <string name="opcao2">English</string>
    <string name="opcao3">Spanish</string>
    <string name="mensagem">A test</string>
</resources>
```

Valores em Espanhol (`/res/values-es/strings.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="opcao1">Estándar</string>
    <string name="opcao2">Inglés</string>
    <string name="opcao3">Español</string>
    <string name="mensagem">Una prueba</string>
</resources>
```

Após definir os valores, utilizamos as chaves no *layout* para exibição nos componentes (na propriedade `text`) (`/res/layout/layout.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mensagem" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/opcao1"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpcao1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/opcao2"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpcao2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/opcao3"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpcao3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fazendo isso seu aplicativo será exibido com o mesmo idioma do sistema, caso não exista uma pasta *values* que corresponda ao idioma selecionado, será utilizada a *default* (`/res/values/strings.xml`).

Se você quiser utilizar um idioma no aplicativo diferente do sistema, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        Button btnOpcao1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpcao1);
        Button btnOpcao2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpcao2);
        Button btnOpcao3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpcao3);

        btnOpcao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLocale("pt");
            }
        });

        btnOpcao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLocale("en");
            }
        });

        btnOpcao3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setLocale("es");
            }
        });

    }

    private void setLocale(String localeName) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeName);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}
```

O método `setLocale` define a localidade nas configurações do seu aplicativo. Para que o idioma seja alterado, é necessário reiniciar o aplicativo. Você pode recuperar os valores das chaves manualmente dessa maneira:

```
String nomeAplicacao = getResources().getString(R.string.nome_aplicacao);
```

Se o usuário trocar o idioma do sistema frequentemente, as configurações do aplicativo serão reajustadas a cada alteração, uma maneira de contornar isso é utilizando [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), segue um exemplo simples de sua utilização:

```
private void setPreferenceLocale(String localeName) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("locale", localeName); // "locale" será a sua chave
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

private String getPreferenceLocale() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    // pega o valor da sua chave, caso ela não exista, retorna "pt_BR"
    return sharedPreferences.getString("locale", "pt_BR");
}
```

**Referências:**

[Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)
[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#LocaleQualifier)
[Change language programatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)
[Android-sharedpreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572780/android-sharedpreference)

**Extras:**

[Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)
[Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)
[PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html)

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira Suas duas edições nessa respostas foram rejeitadas. A primeira você altera coisas que modificam o sentido da resposta, a segunda edição as alterações são irrelevantes. As edições devem tentar melhorar o conteudo do post, mas sem alterar o contexto do autor. Veja algumas dicas [neste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)